How to avoid "Field does not exist in the model" error after deleting a field in code and view Odoo
Is there a way to avoid the field does not exist in the model error when deleting a field in both Code and XML? So my problem is that when I try to delete a field and already have an existing database I cant restart Odoo without getting the error in the title, Odoo somehow thinks the deleted field is still present in the view, even though I deleted it everywhere. My guess is that the old view file is still getting used while the new python file is getting used, thats why the field does not exist.
In the past I fixed this through creating a new database but there are some cases where i can`t just create a new database to fix this. So is there a better way to avoid or fix this Error?

After deleting the the field in model (python codes) and view (XML), you have to do following

Restart Odoo process so that python changes are effective on the Odoo application
Update affected module from Odoo apps list, so that the changes are applied to the current database, if needed columns are dropped from table, views that are updated also updated in the database.
Lastly, any other use currently logged in should reload their tab/browser so that the updated view is also loaded

This will ensure that the error doesn't appear in your current database. There is no need to create a new database for this at all.
